# Cannot update a record via Prisma due to "Unique constraint failed"

Tags: database, postgresql, next.js, orm, prisma

I have the following prisma schema (Postgres)

```
model Member {
  id             String           @id @default(uuid())
  token          String           @unique @default(uuid())
  summary        Summary[]
}

model Summary {
  id           String   @id @default(uuid())
  date         DateTime @db.Date
  activityTime Int
  memberToken  String
  member       Member   @relation(fields: [memberToken], references: [id])

  @@unique([date, memberToken])
}
```

I am trying to update a record of Summary or create if it doesn't exist:

```js
const summary = await prismadb.summary.findUnique({
  where: {
    date_memberToken: {
      date,
      memberToken: payload.token,
    },
  },
});

console.log({summary}); // returns null even if the record already created

if (summary) {
  await prismadb.summary.update({
    where: {
      id: summary.id,
    },
    data: {
      activityTime: {
        increment: timeSpentInc,
      },
    },
  });
} else {
  await prismadb.summary.create({
    data: {
      date,
      activityTime: timeSpentInc,
      member: {
        connect: {
          token: payload.token,
        },
      },
    },
  });
}
```

It creates a record first time, but fails when I try to update it:

```
"Invalid `prisma.summary.create()` invocation: 
Unique constraint failed on the fields: (`date`,`memberToken`)"
```

It also can't find the record that was just created.

I tried via upsert as well, but the result is the same:

```js
await prismadb.summary.upsert({
  where: {
    date_memberToken: {
      memberToken: payload.token,
      date,
    },
  },
  update: {
    activityTime: {
      increment: timeSpentInc,
    },
  },
  create: {
    date,
    activityTime: timeSpentInc,
    member: {
      connect: {
        token: payload.token,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: @Zegarek `date` is a Date object. With directive `db.Date` I try to keep only date-part without a specific time. I tried to convert it to a `String`, but facing the same problem. I didn't try explicit relation name, but let me try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed the problem.

The problem was that the `Summary` model referenced the `id` field in `Member` instead of `token`. Because exactly the **token** was used to update a record.

I updated the relation in this line:

```
member   Member   @relation(fields: [memberToken], references: [token])
```

It fixed the issue.